# How to hide a gridview column in a button click event out side gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a `gridview` as shown below and i want to hide a column named `FREQ_BAND`
,second column in button click named `btnPmtCalculation` which is out side gridview .How to do this ? i reached till this code but not able to proceed

```
<asp:gridview id="gvSpectrum" runat="server" headerstyle-cssclass="HomeGridHeader"
                        allowpaging="True" rowstyle-wrap="false" autogeneratecolumns="False" cssclass="table table-striped table-bordered"
                        cellpadding="4" datakeynames="FEES_CALC_FORMULA,BAND_ID,BAND,FREQ_BAND,SPECTRUM_ID" horizontalalign="Left" showfooter="true"
                        pagesize="10" onpageindexchanging="gvSpectrum_PageIndexChanging" onrowcommand="gvSpectrum_RowCommand">
                          <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "sl_num" HeaderText="SN" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "FREQ_BAND" HeaderText="Frequency Band" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "BW" HeaderText="Bandwidth / Quantity" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "RANGE" HeaderText="Range" />
                          </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
<asp:button id="btnPmtCalculation" runat="server" text="Generate Permenant Sepctrum Invoice" onclick="btnPmtCalculation_Click">
```

Code I did as shown below

```
 protected void btnPmtCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bool  pemenant = true;
      int spectrum_id = 0;
      //Button btn = (Button)sender;

      ////Get the row that contains this button
      //GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSpectrum.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                row.Cells[1].Visible = true;
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Button click is outside gridview,so i cant think of gridview events,first gridview loads,then i am clicking the button outside gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**OnRowCreated**

```
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
         e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Visible = false;
}
```

If you don't prefer the hard-coded index, the only workaround I can suggest is to provide a HeaderText for the GridViewColumn and then find the column using that HeaderText.

```
protected void UsersGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataControlField)UsersGrid.Columns
            .Cast<DataControlField>()
            .Where(fld => fld.HeaderText == "Email")
            .SingleOrDefault()).Visible = false;
}
```

**OnButtonClick**

```
protected void btnPmtCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvSpectrum.Columns[Index].Visible = false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Button click is outside gridview,so i cant think of gridview events,first gridview loads,then i am clicking the button outside gridview

Comment: you can use 
`gridview.Columns[Index].visible=false;`
take a look at [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1768366.aspx?hide+gridview+column+after+button+click+)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just hide the column in the button click.

```
protected void btnPmtCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvSpectrum.Columns[i].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code with this:

```
protected void btnPmtCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          bool  pemenant = true;
          int spectrum_id = 0;
          int columnIndex = 1;
          gvSpectrum.Columns[columnIndex].Visible = false;
}
```

'columnIndex' The column number is for hide it

or if you want hide with column Header Text Use this code:

```
protected void btnPmtCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach(DataControlField col in gvSpectrum.Columns)
        {
            if (col.HeaderText == "Email")
                col.Visible = false;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void btnPmtCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvSpectrum.Columns[columnindex].Visible = false;
    //OR
    gvSpectrum.Columns["columnname"].Visible = false;
}
```